# System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. We don't recognize the field prefix Contract

Tags: email-template, singleemailmessage

I am getting the error when i execute the sendEmailContractDetailsToOwner() method from ContractsService class. My email template has couple of merge fields such {{{Contract.ContractNumber}}}

Domain Class:

```
public void generateEmailContractDetailsToOwner(fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow) {
    EmailTemplate temp = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate 
                            WHERE DeveloperName = 'Contract_Details_1709130195041' 
                            WITH SYSTEM_MODE];
    for(Contract contract : getContracts()) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] { contract.Owner.Email };
        email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        email.setTemplateId(temp.Id);
        email.setTargetObjectId(contract.OwnerId);
        email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        uow.registerEmail(email);
    }
}
```

Service Class Impl:

```
public void sendEmailContractDetailsToOwner(Set<Id> contractIds) {
    fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance(new List<SObjectType>{ EmailMessage.SObjectType });
    Set<String> extraFields = new Set<String>{'Owner.Name', 'Owner.Email'};
    List<Contract> contracts = new ContractsSelector().selectByIdWithExtraFields(contractIds, extraFields);
    IContracts domain = (IContracts) Application.Domain.newInstance(contracts);
    domain.generateEmailContractDetailsToOwner(uow);
    try {
        uow.commitWork();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Logger.error(ex.getTypeName() + ' - ' + ex.getMessage());
        Logger.saveLog();
        throw ex;
    }  
}
```

Service Class:

```
public static void sendEmailContractDetailsToOwner(List<Contract> contracts) {
    Set<Id> contractIds = (new Map<Id, Contract>(contracts)).keySet();
    service().sendEmailContractDetailsToOwner(contractIds);
}
```

Comment: Does the contextual user have at least read access for the `Contract` object type? Also note that using an email address with `setToAddresses` uses your daily email allowance, while sending to a `setTargetObjectId` does not. Remove the setting of the "to addresses".

Comment: Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(temp.Id, contract.OwnerId, contract.Id);

Comment: @PhilW Thank you for sharing the tip about setTargetObjectId, it's incredibly helpful for me, and I truly appreciate it. Following your suggestion, I investigated further and all the record owners has read access to contract records. But during debuggin i realized that email body is not getting created and being stored inside uow. Using Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate() method fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I suggest you add a self-answer explaining the reason for the error and mark it as best answer.

Comment: BTW the limits are used even with a target object if it is not a `User`.

Comment: Just followed your suggestion and answered my question. Thanks again for the provided informations. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following method worked for me as it allows to use setWhatId with User recipient.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(
       temp.Id, 
       contract.OwnerId, 
       contract.Id);
email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
```

Comment: you can accept your own answer as a service to the community

Comment: method worked but i relized that each renderStoredEmailTemplate() call counts against SOQL limit. Therefore, it requires a workaround rather than using it inside a for loop.